# QTableWidget print table on paper

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I am writing program using Qt. Program result - `QTableWidget` object. Can I print this table on paper without any conversion to excel, pdf, etc? Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

QPrinter is a paint device, you can render your widget with that.

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog printer_dialog(&printer);
if (printer_dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    your_widget->render(&painter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take of look at `QDocument`. Use e.g. a `QTextstream` to construct a html-structure from your table. Use `setHtml` to set the document content. Now you can use `print` to print with a `QPrinter`.